# Range of function $y=(e^x-e^{-x})/(e^x+e^{-x})$

Tags: functions

What will be the range of function $y=(e^x-e^{-x})/(e^x+e^{-x})$ ? 
How should I approach this category of problems with exponential functions?  Please Help.

Comment: Just to verify, you are talking about the function otherwise described as $y=\tanh x$, yes?

Comment: You are right.But actually I don't really know much about hyperbolic functions,so for the time being lets not use tanh x.  :-P

Comment: Solve that equation for $x$ and you'll see what are the valid values of $y$.

Comment: **Hint:** $y = \frac{e^{2x}-1}{e^{2x}+1}$.

Comment: @SimonS: I'm not sure that's useful in this context...

Comment: -1<y<1 am i right ?

Comment: It's very useful. Building on the algebraic step Sammy just gave

$$e^{2x} = \frac{1+y}{1-y}$$

which necessarily means that $\frac{1+y}{1-y} > 0$. We have immediately that $y < 1$ and $y > -1$. There is a value of $x$ that attains every value of $y$ in that open interval, hence the range is $(-1, + 1)$.

Comment: I guess you made a calculation mistake @SimonS its -1<y<1

Comment: @SimonS: you're right, I was under the mistaken impression that it was difficult to do such an inversion.

Comment: @SanchayanDutta, look again at what I've written. Same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to analyze the possible values the given function can take on is to transform it into the "simplest possible" form.  Some arithmetic we might apply could look like this:

$$y=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}\\
=\frac {e^{2x}-1}{e^{2x}+1}\\
=1-\frac 2{e^{2x}+1}$$

We could go further with this directly and fully invert the function, but we can immediately make some conclusions from where we are now:

- $e^{2x}+1\in(1,\infty)$
- $\frac 2{e^{2x}+1}\in(0,2)$

This leads us to $y\in(-1,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

You have $y=f(x)$. Solve for $x=g(y)$. Now find the domain for $g(y)$. That would be your "range".